# Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, spring-mvc, https, http-proxy

Hi I am using `HttpsURLConnection` to connect external service it works for few transaction but after some time it fails and get below error

```
Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

I print `connection.getErrorStream()` it gives `null`

Please find below code it is failing at os = connection.getOutputStream();

```
connection = restConfiguration.getSSLConnection(url, connection);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + authorization);
os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(signOrderRequest.toJson().getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.flush();
```

Any suggestions, ideas?

Comment: What is `restConfiguration`?

Comment: It is object where we connect to ssl method

Answer (score 1):

We were facing the same problem, and we just found out that calling

```
URL.openConnection()
```

without a `proxy` parameter doesn't mean that no proxy will be used, but rather that the system proxy will be.

That's why it may seem ok at first, but then fail after a while (when the system proxy is set by another user/process).

If you absolutely don't want any proxy to be used, you have to use :

```
URL.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
```

Max